# How to use class as a parameter in static method

Tags: c#

I have a static method (relevant) inside a class that process XML documents (not so relevant). The method looks like this...

```
public static bool ProcessFormFile(IFormFile formFile, ModelStateDictionary modelState, string fileExtensionToValidate = "docx")
{
    //...some logic & stuff
    MemberInfo property = typeof(UploadTemplateViewModel).GetProperty(formFile.Name.Substring(formFile.Name.IndexOf(".") + 1));

    //... all the rest
}
```

As you can see i'm using reflection to get some properties from `UploadTemplateViewModel`. The thing is that i need that this class be *dynamic* using another class such as `SomeOtherViewModel` and use it inside the method.

I have tried using something like this...

```
public static bool ProcessFormFile(IFormFile formFile, ModelStateDictionary modelState, T entity, string fileExtensionToValidate = "docx") where T : class
```

... but i get `Constraints are not allowed on non-generic declarations`. This is a topice that i've always wanted to learn more about but this is the first time that i use it in a real case scenario.

How can i achieve this? Changing method from static to public or something like that? Thanks in advance.

The method works, and i can get property via reflection, i just need to use `typeof(somethingInMethodParameters).GetProperty()`

Comment: You don't necessarily have to pass in an instance of your object type either. If it's a statically known type and you don't need an instance, you could leave that out and specify the generic parameter in your calls. i.e., `MyClass.ProcessFormFile<MyForm>(formFile, modelState)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't matter that your method is static/public/whatever, the error message you see here is because you have missed the generic type specifier. For example:

```
public static bool ProcessFormFile<T>(...) where T : class
//                                ^^^
//                                Add this
```

And now you can use `T` in the reflection code:

```
MemberInfo property = typeof(T).GetProperty(...)
```

Comment: Thanks DavidG, worked like a charm. In fact, i'm using this pattern with generic repositories but didn't "notice" at all. I've been developing with C# for some years and always dodge somewaht this topic when in fact can save lots of time and keep DRY.